# What are the implications if the Sun was formed in a warm nebula?

Tags: temperature, formation, nebula, hydrogen, 67p

Molecular oxygen O2 has been found on comet 67P/C-G in a ratio of 3.8% to water, which is much higher than expected. An explanation proposed is that the Solar System formed from a molecular cloud warmer at 45 K, than typical molecular clouds at 10 K. I speculate this could have had many kinds of consequences for the Solar System and wonder what the most important or easiest to detect would be.

For example, my uneducated guess would be that more hydrogen escapes from warmer clouds. Exoplanets with low density could then be the result of higher hydrogen abundance, more frequently than here giving them large hydrogen atmospheres.

[News article](http://www.nature.com/news/rosetta-sniffs-oxygen-around-comet-67p-1.18658)

[Ten minutes radio interview](http://www.abc.net.au/science/audio/2015/11/04/4343809.htm?topic=space)

*(Haven't found any paper)*

[image]

*A star forming molecular cloud, for decoration.*

Comment: Is it my imagination, or is that nebula giving me the finger?

Comment: @userLTK I didn't intend to be rude, it's from the wikipedia article on molecular clouds. Maybe it does, space is queerer than we *can* imagine.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_cloud     I didn't mean to imply you were being rude or distract from the question.  I just thought it was kind of funny.   It's apparently just a small part of the Carina Nebula.    Photo #16 in here:  http://www.buzzfeed.com/kasiagalazka/nebula-shapes-you-didnt-know-existed#.hb7kVjOLQ